# Show that $n^2 + m^2 = 2nm$ is an equivalent relation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics

How can I show this is an equivalence relation:

$nRm ⟺ n^2 + m^2  = 2nm$

I had no problem proving the first two steps (reflexivity and symetric). However, for the transitivity part, I can't get to show it. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $n^2+m^2=2nm\iff(n-m)^2=0\iff n=m$.

Comment: Without using the hint, it looks surprisingly challenging though :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution without the fact that this relation is equivalent to standard equality

let $n^2 + m^2 = 2mn$ and  $m^2 + p^2 = 2mp$. This is equivalent to mRn and pRm

Subtracting the equations, $$n^2 - p^2 = 2m(n-p)$$
$$(n-p)(n+p) = 2m(n-p)$$
So either n = p and nRp trivially or we can divide by $n - p$
$$n+p = 2m$$
$$\frac{n+p}{2} = m$$
$$n^2 + (\frac{n+p}{2})^2 = 2n\frac{n+p}{2}$$
$$n^2 + \frac{n^2+2np+p^2}{4} = n^2+np$$
$$\frac{n^2+2np+p^2}{4} = np$$
$$n^2+2np+p^2 = 4np$$
$$n^2+p^2 = 2np$$
so nRp

Therefore nRm and mRp $\Rightarrow$ nRp